# What's wrong with my SQL COUNT Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, inner-join

```
use prime_minister_2013;

SELECT ministry.pm_name as 'PM Name', 
   ministry.min_begin as 'Commencement Date', 
   ministry.party as 'Party', 
   deputy_pm.deputy_name as 'Deputy Name', 
   governor_general.GG_title as 'Governor General Title',
   governor_general.GG_name as 'Governor General Name',
   COUNT(ministry.pm_name) as 'Times Elected'
   FROM ministry
     INNER JOIN deputy_pm ON ministry.min_nr=deputy_pm.min_nr
     INNER JOIN governor_general on ministry.pm_name=governor_general.pm_name
WHERE ministry.party NOT LIKE '%ALP%' AND ministry.min_begin < '1930%'
GROUP BY ministry.pm_name
ORDER BY ministry.min_begin;
```

The resulting tables display double the amount of Prime Minister's Elected as their name shows up in the `ministry` table and the `governor_general` table.
However the `COUNT` clause is being limited to count only `pm_name` from the `minister table.

The count is correct when the `INNER JOIN`s are taken away.
What's wrong with my query?

governor_general table

```
+--------------+----------------+----------+----------+---------+
|GG_name       |GG_Title        |GG_begin  |GG_end    |pm_name  |
+--------------+----------------+----------+----------+---------+
|Baird J L     |Baron Stonehaven|1925-10-08|1931-01-22|Bruce S M|
+--------------+----------------+----------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data from `governor_general`

Comment: Try `COUNT(DISTINCT ministry.pm_name) `

Comment: damn wrong place please ignore

Answer (score 0):

The problem is coming from one of `joins` - it must contain a 1-n relationship and be returning multiple rows.  So when you count pm_names, it duplicates some entries.

To remove those duplicates, one option it to use `DISTINCT` with `COUNT`.

```
SELECT ...,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ministry.pm_name) as 'Times Elected'
...
```

However, depending on your desired results, you may need to decide which records are the correct ones to return.  Mysql is a little more forgiving with its usage of `GROUP BY` and this is perhaps why you're returning the duplicate counts.

Comment: DISTINCT removes duplicates.  The List in ministry has all the prime ministers elected even if they are elected more than one time.  So to count how many times they were elected before 1930 DISTINCT will only pick them up 1 time for all PMs

Comment: @James -- your true problem is in your `group by`.  You really should `group by` all the fields in your `select` statement.  This would help you figure out where you have duplicated data. `Mysql` is one of the only RDBMS systems that allows this improper `group by` clause, resulting in random results.

Answer (score 0):

Only if there one record per election in the ministry table is this feasible:

```
SELECT ...,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ministry.unique_identifier_field_here) as 'Times Elected'
...
```

As there can be several GG's per elected government period by combining the tables you get a 1 to n problem. Using a PM's name won't help as one PM can span many elections, so I think you have to count the distinct number of ministry records using ID (or whatever is the unique identity for that table)